# Proof that Newton expansion over derivatives has the properties of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, finite-differences

Let's consider a Newton expansion over consecutive derivatives of a function:

$$F(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {-1}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$

Can it be proven that such expansion, when converges, has the properties of an antiderivative? What are the conditions for that if it is not always the case?

Comment: was the earlier answer unsatisfactory?  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130886

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker I think it does not answer the question because it does not mention the other types of differintegral, which I was asking for comparison with. From what I understand, it says that the continuity is difficult to prove. This question is more narrow, it asks about just antiderivative.

Comment: Why do you write $\binom{-1}m$ rather than $\frac{(-1)\cdots(-m)}{m!} = (-1)^m$?  By "properties of an antiderivative", do you mean more than that $\partial F = f$?

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd no, I mean exactly that property.

Comment: Well, the answer is clearly "yes" for $f(x) = \exp(\lambda x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ with $|\lambda-1|<1$, and therefore for linear combinations of such functions (more generally, e.g., if your Fourier transform has compact support in the interior of the disk).  But I'm sure there are cases where F converges in some not-great way to some not-very-regular function.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd Can you give an example where it converges, but not to an antiderivative?

Comment: @Anixx Not off the top of my head.  It's not really my area.